# error creating form bean

Tags: java

the error is:

```
10:44:18,520 INFO  [STDOUT] - Error creating form bean of class com.getcare.crud.web.StudentForm
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.getcare.remote.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:8)
    at com.getcare.crud.remote.StudentStructure.<init>(StudentStructure.java:15)
    at com.getcare.crud.remote.StudentContactInfoStructure.<init>(StudentContactInfoStructure.java:21)
    at com.getcare.crud.remote.StudentStructure.<init>(StudentStructure.java:21)
    at com.getcare.crud.remote.StudentContactInfoStructure.<init>(StudentContactInfoStructure.java:21)
    at com.getcare.crud.remote.StudentStructure.<init>(StudentStructure.java:21)
```

What's the possible error?

Comment: You have an infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1):

From your stack trace, it seems that each `StudentStructure` has a field and initializes a `StudentContactInfoStructure` which has a field and initializes a `StudentStructure`. This causes infinite recursion.

Comment: Thanks sir! ;) I have this StudentContactInfoStructure contact = new StudentContactInfoStructure(); on my StudentStructure. Also I initialize StudentStructure on StudentContactInfoStructure which caused recursion. :D I erased those and my code worked fine. Thanks! :) Big help. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to pin point with out the code. But from the stacktrace you added my guess is you are trying to initialize `StudentStructure` inside `StudentContactInfoStructure`'s constructor and initializing `StudentContactInfoStructure` inside `StudentStructure`'s constructor. Hence it is going into infinite loop of the calls and throwing stackoverflow error

Comment: Thanks sir! ;) I have this StudentContactInfoStructure contact = new StudentContactInfoStructure(); on my StudentStructure. Also I initialize StudentStructure on StudentContactInfoStructure which caused recursion. :D I erased those and my code worked fine. Thanks! :) Big help. ;)